# Poner días resaltados en Jquery Datepicker con datos cogidos de una llamada AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un input con id "inputFechaReserva", al cual le he incustrado el calendario de jQuery Datepicker. Mi finalidad es que en el calendario resalte ciertas fechas que cojo de una base de datos. El código funciona si meto las fechas a mano en la variable eventDates asi:

```
eventDates[ new Date( '08/07/2016' )] = new Date( '08/07/2016' );
```

Pero con el código que tengo ahora mismo me salen estos errores:

```
VM197:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: eventDates is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at n (main.js? [sm]:19735)
    at Function.globalEval (main.js? [sm]:19999)
    at text script (main.js? [sm]:29259)
    at Q (main.js? [sm]:28407)
    at i (main.js? [sm]:28875)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (main.js? [sm]:29167)
(anonymous) @ VM197:1
n @ main.js? [sm]:19735
globalEval @ main.js? [sm]:19999
text script @ main.js? [sm]:29259
Q @ main.js? [sm]:28407
i @ main.js? [sm]:28875
(anonymous) @ main.js? [sm]:29167
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ main.js? [sm]:29219
ajax @ main.js? [sm]:28826
(anonymous) @ reservas.php:268
d @ main.js? [sm]:23236
h @ main.js? [sm]:23304
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ main.js? [sm]:23342
c @ main.js? [sm]:22970
fireWith @ main.js? [sm]:23100
fire @ main.js? [sm]:23108
c @ main.js? [sm]:22970
fireWith @ main.js? [sm]:23100
ready @ main.js? [sm]:23573
d @ main.js? [sm]:23583
main.js? [sm]:29219 GET http://localhost:3000/ociusparkTPV/dist/eventDates[new%20Date(%20'18/01/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'18/01/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'29/01/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'29/01/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'09/01/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'09/01/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'01/02/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'01/02/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'23/03/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'23/03/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'03/02/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'03/02/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'26/05/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'26/05/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'31/01/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'31/01/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'22/06/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'22/06/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'07/03/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'07/03/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'25/05/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'25/05/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'04/02/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'04/02/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'27/04/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'27/04/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'20/04/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'20/04/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'17/03/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'17/03/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'23/02/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'23/02/2018'%20);eventDates[new%20Date(%20'23/02/2018'%20)]%20=%20new%20Date(%20'23/02/2018'%20);?_=1519211943846 404 (Not Found)
send @ main.js? [sm]:29219
ajax @ main.js? [sm]:28826
pe.(anonymous function) @ main.js? [sm]:28975
getScript @ main.js? [sm]:28960
success @ reservas.php:272
c @ main.js? [sm]:22970
fireWith @ main.js? [sm]:23100
i @ main.js? [sm]:28925
(anonymous) @ main.js? [sm]:29167
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ main.js? [sm]:29219
ajax @ main.js? [sm]:28826
(anonymous) @ reservas.php:268
d @ main.js? [sm]:23236
h @ main.js? [sm]:23304
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ main.js? [sm]:23342
c @ main.js? [sm]:22970
fireWith @ main.js? [sm]:23100
fire @ main.js? [sm]:23108
c @ main.js? [sm]:22970
fireWith @ main.js? [sm]:23100
ready @ main.js? [sm]:23573
d @ main.js? [sm]:23583
VM199:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at n (main.js? [sm]:19735)
    at Function.globalEval (main.js? [sm]:19999)
    at text script (main.js? [sm]:29259)
    at Q (main.js? [sm]:28407)
    at i (main.js? [sm]:28875)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (main.js? [sm]:29167)
```

Sé que los errores son de la manera de llamar a los datos, he probado varias cosas diferentes pero no consigo el resultado que espero.
Este es mi código HTML:

Este mi código JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    var eventDates = {};
  // Señalamos en el datepicker los días en los que hay alguna reserva realizada (en el CSS es la clase "event a")
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'script',
      url: 'controller/reservas/reservasControllerMostrarFechasReservas.php',
      success: function (res) {
        $.getScript(res);
      }
    });
    alert(eventDates[1]);
    $('#inputFechaReserva').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var highlight = eventDates[date];
        if (highlight) {
          return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
        } else {
          return [true, '', ''];
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Y este mi código php, archivo 1 llamado "reservasControllerMostrarFechasReservas.php":

```
<?php

  require_once('../../model/reserva.php');

  $reserva = new Reserva();

  $reserva -> mostrarFechasReservas();

?>
```

Archivo 2 de PHP llamado "reserva":

```
<?php

  require_once('conexion.php');


  class Reserva extends Conexion
  {
public function mostrarFechasReservas()
    {

      parent::conectar();

      $consulta = 'SELECT fecha_reserva FROM reservas';

      $fecha = parent::query($consulta);

      $verificar_final = parent::verificarRegistros($consulta);

      while ($fechas = mysqli_fetch_array($fecha)){
        echo "eventDates[new Date( '".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fechas['fecha_reserva']))."' )] = new Date( '".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fechas['fecha_reserva']))."' );";
      }

      parent::cerrar();
    }
}
?>
```